# Show more than 10 location using Gmap

Tags: google-maps

I am using Gmap + location for show my store locations on my page.

I have added near about 50 locations. However on map it is showing only 10 locations.

I want to show more than 10 locations. Can you please let me know how it is possible.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply - edit your pager options in view to fit your needs.

Comment: is it ok now? Do you have any answer regarding the same?

Comment: Edit your gmap view, and change pager to show all items.

Comment: I have already done the same.
I am using pager for display all items.

Comment: Also, in backend section for that block, all locations are showing at the bottom where contents are showing. However in front only 10 locations are showing.

I have searched a lot regarding the issue. But I didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

down vote accept

Fixed.

When we use Gmap then at that time we create a attachment for show all the locations on the single map. And for show all the locations in Map we need to go under attachment of created view and then set the "Use pager" display all item or any specific number of items.

If we set pager under block or page then it will show the full location in text just below the map. However, marker won't show on page. And for this we need to go with attachment section.

Thanks.